# Netbeans missing File Type | Category | Other

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7

not sure what happened here & can't seem to find any literature explaining how to fix it.

I literally fired up netbeans the other day, and tried to create a new folder, but I'm missing the 'other' category. Tried uninstalling & reinstalling (on OSX), & even upgraded (was 7.0.1, now 7.1.1). Which leads me to believe it's a preference or a setting somewhere. . .

Has anybody seen this before ?

[image: Has anybody seen this before ??]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had tried adding templates in the template manager, but that didn't fix my issue. I eventually removed all Netbeans v7.1 from my system and upgraded to v7.2.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I tried to drag'n'drop file from archive. I don't know how it can be but templates from 'other' folder appeared instead of my file. Maybe it's a bug. I didn't get what happened then and deleted all these files. Maybe something similar happened in your case.

So you need to add templates manually in Template Manager (Tools -> Templates).

Comment: Tried the template manager - didn't fix it.  I wound up upgrading to 7.2.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by choosing "Templates" from the "Tools" menu, and then adding a new folder and calling it "Other". When I did this, the folder instantly filled with all the items that had been in the original "Other" folder.